# How to end the game once it has touched an image in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I was wondering how I could end the game or stop the game from running after the player sprite touches the other sprite or the variable platform12. The following is what I have done so far:

```
        platform12 = gameSprites.GameObject(pygame.Vector2(2600, 500), pygame.Vector2(150, 50), "diamond_ore.png")

        self.platforms.add(self.ground, platform1, platform2, platform3, platform4, platform5, platform6, platform7, platform8, platform9, platform10, platform11, platform12)

        #PLAYER
        self.player = gameSprites.Player(pygame.Vector2(0, 450), pygame.Vector2(30, 40), pygame.Vector2(0, 0), "steve.png")
        self.player_objects.add(self.player)
```

Comment: You return out from your functions and game loop. If you need to return from several functions, then you probably need to return with an exit code.

Comment: I was wondering what this code has to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `collidepoint()` method. Refer to this link:
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html?highlight=collidepoint#pygame.Rect.collidepoint

Answer (score 0):

If the player and platforms both have `rect`, then you could simply check for collision using `collidrect` and write `pygame.quit()` if the condition is true.

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect